# how to assign selector to an object class in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, pageobjects

I'm trying to assign the selector to one of my object classes by using cypress. but it doesn't work for me. here is the error I got

> stocksTradePage.getStocksSearch(...).getInputField is not a function

here are my classes.

stocksShare.js

```
const locators = {
  inputField: 'input',
};

class StocksSearch {
  getInputField() {
    return cy.get(locators.inputField);
  }
}

module.exports = StocksSearch;
```

stocksTradePage.js

```
import StocksSearch from './stocksSearch'

const locators = {
  strocksSearch: '[data-cy=stock-search-field]',
};

let stocksSearch = new StocksSearch();

class StocksTradePage {
  getStocksSearch() {
    stocksSearch = cy.get(locators.strocksSearch);
    return stocksSearch;
  }
}

module.exports = StocksTradePage;
```

testStocksPage

```
import StocksTradePage from '../../support/trade/stroksTradePage'

const stocksTradePage = new StocksTradePage();

describe('global nav test', () => {
  it('test input field', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/trade');
    stocksTradePage.getStocksSearch().getInputField().type('aaaa');
  });
});
```

Comment: What is that you’re tying to do in your tests? Meaning can you write the entire `cy.get()` that you want in your test ?

Comment: I can use cy.get() in my test, but I want to create some component object classes and reuse them on different pages.

Comment: What I meant was what is the final `cy.get()` statement you want in your test, i can then use your component object classes to achieve that.